# What is the best approach to select multiple values from a list of values in ascending order?

Tags: forms, input-fields

I have a section in a webapp where the user can select from a series of values, which are displayed in ascending order (to perform an unspecified function). The user can select among any of these values. The screenshot below is an example of an acceptable input.

Is there a better way to display these values? At first glance, it doesn't really convey that the values are in ascending order.

i.e.

- Should I arrange them from left to right instead of top down?
- Should I put all options in a single horizontal or vertical line?
- Is there a better solution than using checkboxes as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Can values increase by 25, 90, and 95 percent at the same time? Is this for a large screen environment, or should it also work on small screen/touch devices?

Comment: Is the user required to select among these discrete values or can they select any value in a given range?

Comment: @greenforest I believe what the OP implies by increasing values is that the values are in an ascending order.

Comment: The screenshot is exactly what is intended. The user can select any one or multiple of those inputs, which are percentage values arranged in ascending order.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I see using checkboxes is that while it allows choice selection, it does not offer a visual representation of:

- The type of action being performed
- The value increasing
- The start / end location of the selected values

---

There is a [Moodle plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/block_completion_progress) that allows to select steps in an intuitive and visual way within a progress bar:

[image]

With an adaptation of this idea, a quantity bar can be made with the possibility of selecting / deselecting each of its steps:

[image]

Comment: Really like your take on this. While I have designed this `n` number of times, I've honestly never given it much thought. I was gonna post the same answer but held back to see what others come up with.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I arrange them left to right instead of top down?

The right answer depends on the user's feedback and should come out from an A/B testing or usability testing result, if possible. Typically in the mobile device, we're used to for both horizontal and vertical direction, but that's also dependent on the real-state that is present there along with other contents. Typically, the user is more flexible in changing the value with the horizontal view, but that's not a rule too. If the value changes happen with the favorable interaction zone for users, you can use one of the choices.

> Should I put all options on a single horizontal or vertical line?

If you mean Slider, you should choose that since it is largely used in the other designs and gives a kinda proper view for changing values.

> Is there a better solution than using checkboxes like this?

Slider can be a better solution and not checkboxes, since checkboxes are typically used for checking multiple values. If you're determined to use checkboxes, then I'd recommend using Radio buttons since they restrict the user from choosing multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would suggest you avoid more than one row or column as it creates too much cognitive load for the user.

Re the answer above, neither sliders nor radio buttons allow for multiple selections. If you need users to select multiple values from the list then checkboxes is the correct design convention.